# Datagrid view updating issue

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

Workflow:   I have this iterate through a datagridview, updating the value of `BillingStatus` for all selected cells.  There is a value in a text box labeled `liststatus.text`.

Issue:  It doesn’t update the last selected cell.   If I select 10 cells, it only updates 9 cells, and the resultant table only shows 9 changes. However, the `DataGridView` shows all 10 changes.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dvBILLING.SelectedCells 'For x = 0 To dvBILLING.SelectedCells.Count - 1
        dvBILLING.Item("BillingStatus", cell.RowIndex).Value = listStatus.Text
        dvBILLING.Update()
        dvBILLING.EndEdit()
        dvBILLING.Refresh()
    Next

    Dim junkt = dsbilling.Tables(0).GetChanges
    fnsave()

Refresh()
skip:
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I had to end up doing was ClearSelection then set CurrentCell to Nothing. This way it took the last saved result.